# MySql data not showing on html form until page is refreshed

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have attempted to research this one and have also tried a number of fixes, all ending up a mess. I am  novice with this and am aware I am using a deprecated version of PHP, code is not my job however I am stuck with fixing this for work because I will benefit by reducing errors and getting other people on board to maintain data. I am changing a PHP / MySQL application that was once all full of hard coded select boxes, I have created a small html form to CRUD a set of department names in a table called 'departments'  and am now cross referencing this across the site. 
The mysql 'department' table has 3 fields department_id, status, department_name

The form I am having trouble with updates a table called 'staff' it allows to CRUD this data in the staff table however on page load of the form it  does not populate the department name it shows an empty select box.
The relevant field from the 'staff' table is staff_company.
 I am able to open up a drop down box which is populated with all the correct options, if i leave the box untouched and update other data on the form it posts the original correct department_id maintaining the integrity of the data and on refreshing the page the correct department name does show. It is an issue if anyone else uses it as they may think that the field is empty when they try to edit and may make an incorrect selection, it is also sloppy, my thoughts are that I am somehow not declaring the variable early enough any suggestions in novice talk / beginner talk will be appreciated part of code below - plus I need to understand where I am going wrong so I can improve my skills (note page approximately 1600 lines therefore not posting whole page).

```
//editing departments using department id//
            $select_dept_names = "SELECT *
                FROM `departments` 
                WHERE status = 'active' 
                ORDER BY department_name ASC ";             
            $run_select_dept = mysql_query($select_dept_names,$link); 

            print(" <tr><td id='employee_left'>Department:</td><td><select name=\"staff_company\"> 
             <option value=\"".$grab_staff['staff_company']."\">".$dept_data['department_name']."</option>");

            while($dept_data=mysql_fetch_array($run_select_dept))           
                    {
                    print("<option value=\"".$dept_data['department_id']."\">".$dept_data['department_name']."</option>");

                    }print("
                    </select></td></tr>");
```

Many thanks in advance - Cheers Jase

Updated code below

```
//line 346 queries      

    $select_dept_names = "SELECT * FROM departments 
                        ORDER BY department_name ASC ";     

// line 363 - storing and fetching data
    $run_select_dept = mysql_query($select_dept_names,$link);
    $dept_data = mysql_fetch_array($run_select_dept);


// line 1147 - editing departments using department id///////////NEEDS WORK     Only showing first department then on F5 displays existing department
            //var_dump($main_report[department]); die(); - outputs only one     line from the 'department' table  
            if($main_report['department'] = $dept_data['department_id'])
            {
            print(" <table id='edit_table_within'>Department:</td><td>    <select name=\"department\"> 
             <option     value=\"".$main_report['department']."\">".$dept_data['department_name']."    </option>");
            }
            else print("<table id='edit_table_within'>Department:</td><td>     <select name=\"department\"> <option value=\"\">Select..</option>");

            while($dept_data=mysql_fetch_array($run_select_dept))           
                    {
                    print("<option      value=\"".$dept_data['department_id']."\">".$dept_data['department_name']."     </option>");

                    }print("
                    </select></td></tr>");
```

Comment: No errors being reported? I figure at least you'd be getting undefined variable `$dept_data` from your first usage of it.. `status` is a reserved keyword try putting that in backticks. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @chris85 Nope - no errors at all, I have not had any issues with status either.

Comment: But do you have error reporting on and/or displaying (if not displaying are you checking log). Try adding check for errors, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considerable time bashing the code around I have found a solution, this may be ugly and there may be more efficient ways of doing this however here is the final piece of code that works for me

```
//editing departments using department id//
            $select_o_dept_names = "SELECT *
                FROM `departments` 
                WHERE department_id = ".$main_report['department']."";              
            $run_select_o_dept = mysql_query($select_o_dept_names,$link); 
            $dept_o_data=mysql_fetch_array($run_select_o_dept);

            $select_dept_names = "SELECT *
                FROM `departments` 
                WHERE status = 'active' 
                ORDER BY department_name ASC ";             
            $run_select_dept = mysql_query($select_dept_names,$link); 

            print("<table id='edit_table_within'>Department:</td><td><select name=\"department\"> 
             <option value=\"".$main_report['department']."\">".$dept_o_data['department_name']."</option>");

            while($dept_data=mysql_fetch_array($run_select_dept))           
                    {
                    print("<option value=\"".$dept_data['department_id']."\">".$dept_data['department_name']."</option>");

                    }print("
                    </select></td></tr>");
```

Comment: All you did was add the already set option at the top of the select. What you were missing (assuming you don't want that entry in the list twice) is to check if `$dept_data['department_id'] == $main_report['department']` and if it is, adding the [selected](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) attribute to the element.

Comment: @ssnobody I am a newb at this stuff and had been stretching my brain on how to get the relational variable to load when the page first loads, it was loading on refresh (F5) and I used var_dump()  in an attempt to track down the problem. Up until adding this code I was getting a blank select (the variable was not declared). ... Yes I would love not to list the item twice in my select drop down but I have failed miserably at getting it to work apart from using this code above. I wont feel insulted if a suggested code fix is posted. Many thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding you well enough(and I'm probably not) I would recommend adding a peice of code that automatically refreshes the page when you confirm that data has been added or changed into database. Also you have a blank box in dropdown boxes because you are selecting a default option. Hope I'm understanding your question

Comment: .....great  I think you are onto it; what I am trying to do is set the "default option" to whatever the currently selected option is in my database, and I need to reference the option by id and return the name in the select box. So I need to understand how do I set the default option.

Comment: I also do have error reporting on and in this case no errors ....and believe me I have seen lots in my time of working on this.....

Comment: something along the lines of       echo '<option value=\"'.$dept_data['department_id'].'\"';

if($condition == $whatyoulookingfor){echo ' selected';}

echo ' >'.$dept_data['department_name'].'</option>';

Comment: I would also advise you too use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Great - that looks like what I am after - I will do some reading on prepared statements too as this is relatively new to me it will probably take a while.

Comment: your other issue of the refresh. check that something changed in database then refresh.  sample code:                                     $affected_rows = $query->rowCount(); if (affected_rows > 0){echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>");}

Comment: Apologies, my mistake, error reporting for php was on but not for mysql. The variable $dept_data['department_id'] returned null. I have altered the code but on checking by using var_dump ($dept_data['department_id']) only the first row of the table is returned (as it is ordered by ascending). I will have modified the question showing the changed code at the end  (to see changes from original question)